# Ввод цифры в alert

Tags: javascript

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь вводил в prompt цифру 1 то ему показывалась картинка с информацией.Если бы он вводил цифру 2, то ему показывалась другая картинка с информацией.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру вот так:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script>
    var digit = prompt("Введите число 1 или 2", 0);
    if (digit == 0){
        alert("Только 1 или 0");
    }

    if (digit == 1){
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML='<img src="1.jpg">';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }else{
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '<img src="2.jpg">';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

</script>
</html>
```